# Get the total size of the TCheckbox, including box and text, in Delphi

Tags: delphi, checkbox, size

I want to get the total size of the TCheckbox, including the box and the text in Delphi. I check the article at [Delphi FMX TCheckbox/TRadiobutton Autosize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492184/delphi-fmx-tcheckbox-tradiobutton-autosize), but it seems that TCheckbox does not have a Canvas property so the code does not fit for it.

**Update**

Let me explain the reason why I need to know that. In some of my checkboxes, I need to put a spinedit related to the checkbox. For example, in checkbox "Split the file when it size larger than" ### "Bytes", where ### is the spin edit.

Since checkbox does not support auto-size, one way is to enlarge the checkbox so that it accomondate all the texts. Then put the spin edit after the last visible character.

This is fine for single language, however, to support multi-langauge, some language will be very longer than the others.

In such a case, I can choose:

1. Calculate the size of the checkbxo visible part.

or

2. Keep some spaces between the last visible character and the spin edit.

method 2 is not very good as there will be huge distance between the checkbox and the spin edit for some languages.

**Update 2**

One more issue, I try to do the same thing for a button, as below:

```
var
  bmp: TBitmap;
  size: TSize;
  width: Integer;
begin
  Checkbox1.Caption := Edit3.Text;
  Button3.Caption := Edit3.Text;

  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bmp.SetSize(CheckBox1.Width, CheckBox1.Height);
    bmp.Canvas.Font := CheckBox1.Font;
    size := bmp.Canvas.TextExtent(CheckBox1.Caption);
    Width := bmp.Canvas.TextWidth(Checkbox1.Caption);
    CheckBox1.Width := size.cx + 20;
    button3.Width := size.cx;
    SpinEdit1.Left := Checkbox1.Left + Checkbox1.Width + 5;
  finally
    bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

As the button does not have any box, so I use the size.cx instead of adding some value. However, in my test, actually the text width is not correct, which makes the button cannot accomondate the whole text, see below:

[image]

Comment: `TCheckBox.Width`? What exactly are you planning on using the size for?

Comment: The question you refer to, concerns an `Fmx` `TCheckBox`. Are you asking about `Vcl` or `Fmx`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, TCheckbox.Width is the width of the whole checkbox control. As Checkbox is not auto-sized to fit the text. The width can be totally different from the actual length of the text + the box.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, I am asking about Vcl controls. I don'know that Vcl and Fmx controls are different in their properties.

Comment: Ok, but please also say for what purpose you want to know the box + text length specifically. What will you do with that knowledge?

Comment: A possible solution is to use a checkbox "Split the file when its size exceeds a number of bytes:" and an edit box on the next line.

Comment: Regarding the `+ 20` you added. Have you tried this on a system with 200% DPI. You might get a surprise.

Comment: Also, regarding "actually the text width is not correct". The text width IS correct, but the button has a border, so the button's effective text area is smaller than the button's width. It's like a square building with external wall size 2 m. That doesn't mean you can fit a 2×2 m^2 carpet inside (unless the walls have 0 mm thickness).

Comment: Yet another solution would be to remove the text from the `TCheckbox`, reduce its width to the same as the height and use a separate `TLabel` for description. A `TLabel` has  `Autosize` and `WordWrap` properties, which you can use as required. At startup (`Form.OnCreate`) set `Lbl.Left := cb.left + cb.width + 5;`.

Comment: And yet, yet another one look for adding the `AutoSize` feature to the `TCheckBox`, meaning of course it would affect only the text part, not the box. I don't know what it takes to do it, and I don't have time right now.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, Your solution of chekcbox without text + label is great and simple! I will use this one. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my two cents.

To get the size of the actual checkbox, I believe you should ask the Win32 theme API (`uses UxTheme`):

```pascal
var
  h: HTHEME;
  S: TSize;
begin

  h := OpenThemeData(Handle, 'BUTTON');
  try

    if Succeeded(GetThemePartSize(h, Canvas.Handle, BP_CHECKBOX,
      CBS_UNCHECKEDNORMAL, nil, TS_DRAW, S))
    then
      ShowMessage('Check box width: ' + S.cx.ToString);

  finally
    CloseThemeData(h);
  end;
```

Similarly, this retrieves the width of the text (caption):

```pascal
var
  h: HTHEME;
  R: TRect;
begin

  h := OpenThemeData(Handle, 'BUTTON');
  try

    if Succeeded(GetThemeTextExtent(h, Canvas.Handle, BP_CHECKBOX,
      CBS_UNCHECKEDNORMAL, PChar(CheckBox1.Caption),
      Length(CheckBox1.Caption), 0, nil, R))
    then
      ShowMessage('Caption width: ' + R.Width.ToString);

  finally
    CloseThemeData(h);
  end;
```

What remains unknown is the padding between the check box and the caption. I don't know the right way to obtain this, but it seems like it is most often the same as the width of a space:

```pascal
var
  h: HTHEME;
  S: TSize;
  R: TRect;
begin

  h := OpenThemeData(Handle, 'BUTTON');
  try

    if Succeeded(GetThemePartSize(h, Canvas.Handle, BP_CHECKBOX,
      CBS_UNCHECKEDNORMAL, nil, TS_DRAW, S))
    then
      ShowMessage('Check box width: ' + S.cx.ToString);

    if Succeeded(GetThemeTextExtent(h, Canvas.Handle, BP_CHECKBOX,
      CBS_UNCHECKEDNORMAL, PChar(#32+CheckBox1.Caption),
      1+Length(CheckBox1.Caption), 0, nil, R))
    then
      ShowMessage('Caption width including padding: ' + R.Width.ToString);

  finally
    CloseThemeData(h);
  end;
```

Comment: Well, "the right way" is probably that you shouldn't need to know this.

Comment: Asking theme API is better, indeed. I will remove my answer after asker has seen it, just in case ...

Comment: @TomBrunberg, why. I think yours is better and it is much more simpler.

Comment: @alancc: Because that approach only gives you the width of the text and not of the actual checkbox?

Comment: Will this also works for a skinned control? I use skin control

Comment: I don't know what a "skinned control" is. It will work for a `TCheckbox` control (which is a standard Win32 BUTTON control).

Comment: I use TbsSkinCheckBox which is a ownder draw control, not standard Win32 button control. Skinned control means it use a specific skin.

Comment: @alancc: The title of your question is "Get the total size of the `TCheckbox`, including box and text, in Delphi" and not once in your text do you mention that you are using a `TbsSkinCheckBox` and not an ordinary `TCheckBox`; instead, you repeatedly talk about `TCheckBox`. Not want to sound harsh or anything, but this is a bit like asking "How can I change the order of channels on a Sony TV?" and after having received a few answers, replying, "Does this work with a Samsung TV? That's the one I have." :)

Comment: I am really sorry about that. Because originally I think the solution to TCheckbox and TbsSkinCheckbox will be the same. So to make the thing simpler, I make a  test program with TCheckbox to make the test. If The solution works, then I will apply it to TbsSkinCheckbox.

Comment: If the custom skinned control differs from a standard Win32 checkbox, the metrics for the Win32 control will not apply, of course. How to do it then entirely depends on the control you are using: you need to ask its developer(s). But if you disregard the size of the checkbox and the spacing, and only care about the text width, you need only to determine [its size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548132/how-to-get-textwidth-of-string-without-canvas).

Comment: Thank you very much.