# Autosizing a checkbox

Tags: delphi

I have setup options for users to set Scale and Font of forms and controls in my program.

For this to work, the controls on a form need to be auto-sized to accommodate the different sized text when the font or scaling changes.

Scaling labels is easy, as they have an `AutoSize` property.  Checkboxes don't have `AutoSize`, so I am trying to work out the checkbox and caption width required.

The closest I got was with:

```
(fname.Components[i] as TCheckBox).Width := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMENUCHECK) + fname.Canvas.TextWidth((fname.Components[i] as TCheckBox).Caption);
```

But that is not 100% correct.  Depending on the monitor resolution, DPI, scaling, or seemingly other random factors, the total size of the checkbox and caption will be undersized (so the caption text is cutoff) or oversized (so the checkbox can expand too far and over any component to the right of it).

Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics shows `SM_CXMENUCHECK` is for "The width of the default menu check-mark bitmap, in pixels", and not the actual checkbox square size.

Does anyone have a reliable way to get the size (in pixels) of a checkbox and the white space before the label text?  No matter what the current user resolution, DPI, UI theme, etc.

Comment: Just do a good guess and add 10% to it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65737733/282848

Comment: Yes! That does help.  Gets exact size of checkbox and label.  Handles form scaling.
Does not handle the UI themes though.  So can lead to some trimming when themes are active.  I added another space to compensate.